# Conditional probability and individual probability

Tags: probability

> Is conditional probability always lesser than original probability of occurrence ?. For example is $P(A|B)< P(A)$ always ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Let $A=B$, then $P(A|B)=1 \ge P(A)$.

Comment: What can we say about P(A/B) and P(B) then, in a general case. My guess is that we cant say anything about whether P(A/B) < or > P(B)

Comment: in general nothing much besides the formula $P(A |B)=\frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ and $B$ are independent, then;
$$P(A|B)=P(A).$$
For example, tossing a fair coin:
$$P(H|T)=P(H).$$